# iterate array to build email body with python

Tags: python, arrays, email, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python and BeautifulSoup to scrape elements (`div`) from a website and send them to myself with an E-mail.

It scrapes the website, takes the element and makes an array with this elements.

How can I iterate this array and put the elements into the email body?

What I tried is:

```
    def sendEmail():

     fromaddr = "<email_address>"
     toaddr = "<email_address>"
     msg = email.message.Message()
     msg['From'] = "<sender>"
     msg['To'] = toaddr
     msg['Subject'] = "<subject>"

     email_content = """
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>Title</title>
      <style type="text/css">
        .some-style {
           some-css: rules;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body> 

      <div class='container'>
        """ + 
    for i in xrange(0,len(my_aray)):
      (my_array[i].prettify()).encode('utf-8')
      + """
      </div>
    </body>
   </html>
    """
      msg.add_header('Content-Type','text/html')
      msg.set_payload(email_content)
      server = smtplib.SMTP('<smtp.server>', <port>)
      server.ehlo()
      server.starttls()
      server.login(fromaddr, "<password>")

      text = msg.as_string()
      server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
      server.quit()
```

Of course this part doesn't work:

```
<div class='container'>
    """ + 
for i in xrange(0,len(my_array)):
  (my_array[i].prettify()).encode('utf-8')
  + """
  </div>
```

If I take each element doing for example `""" + my_array[0] + my_array[1] + """` it works. The problem is that the number of elements into the array can vary.

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try forming your dynamic html content first and then append it to the email_content

**Ex:**

```
html = ""
for i in my_aray:
    html += """<div class='container'>{0}</div><br>""".format(i)

email_content = """
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>Title</title>
      <style type="text/css">
        .some-style {{
           some-css: rules;
        }}
      </style>
    </head>
    <body> 
        {0}
    </body>
   </html>
    """.format(html)

print(email_content)
```

Comment: And how it works if I have to iterate more than one array?

Comment: If I scrape two (or more) websites, and I create two (or more) arrays with the elements of each website, how can I iterate them to put it into the email body? For example I have `my_array_1` and `my_array_2`, and I want to build the email writing a title, then the content of `my_array_1` than another title and the content of `my_array_2`.